# How can I load a property lazily in JDO (on Google App Engine)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, properties, lazy-loading, jdo

I have this code in one of my @PersistenceCapable classes:

```
@Persistent
private Blob data;
```

The `Blob` can be quite big, so I'd like to load it lazily since most of the times I don't need it. How can I annotate that property to avoid immediate loading? I could create another class that contains the `Blob` alone and then use a lazy one-to-one, but I'd like to solve this with annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: Entities in App Engine are loaded and stored in their entirety. If you want to avoid loading it, you'll need to, as you suggest, store it in a separate model. I would suggest benchmarking your app first to see if this is an issue, though.